# Laravel4.2: Eloquent - Use DATE_FORMAT in SQL query

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying this simple sql query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%m-%d-%Y') FROM my_tbl WHERE id = 1
```

in Eloquent like

```
$tbl = DB::table('my_tbl');
$tbl->select( 'DATE_FORMAT(my_date, "%m-%d,-%Y")' );
$tbl->where( 'id', "=", 1);
Datatable::query($tbl);
```

but it accepts as string and throws error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(arrival, \"%d %M, %Y\")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I just add DB::raw and it worked :)

```
$tbl->select( 'DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(my_date, \'%m-%d-%Y\') AS arrival')' );
```